# How can I embed an HTML file that has a supporting document library of information in SharePoint in the cloud?

Tags: sharepoint-online

I have an HTML file that is from Industryprint version 2004 application and it generates a document library when I save it in html format.

Now what I need is to insert that HTML file in SharePoint in the cloud. I hope you can help me.

Comment: You mean that you want to embed the html codes to a SharePoint page? Apologize in advance if I misunderstand.